# How to account for parameters that may or may not be passed, for sql queries?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am writing a function read data as which runs a sql query and performs a select operation. There may or may not be parameters(for "where" in query) that I have to account for.

The function would be something like:

```
readdata("file1",par1="k",par2="b")
```

With this function, I will open the file called file1 which contains sql query
with 2 where statements as

```
"..where take1 = :par1 and take2 := par2"
```

My function has to be able to work with as many parameters (other files) or none of them.

---

I saw in R something like:

```
as.arg.list <- function (...)
{
  argList = list(...)
  if (length(argList)==0)
    return (list())
  return (argList)
}
```

Is there something similar in python?

---

sql files will not be changed!!!

Comment: Make your statement like this: `select .... from.... where 1=1 `. And then just go in the loop over your parameter -value pair and add `and {field goes here} = {value goes here}`

Comment: Will not change sql files!!

Comment: Frankly, you can do anything you want. Its your code

Comment: sql files are used by other programs so messing them up is the last option but i figured it out. USE: **kwargs and *args

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, that would be

```
where (take1 = :par1 or :par1 is null)
  and (take2 = :par2 or :par2 is null)
```

Comment: the sql files cannot be edited.. I need to change my function so that my function can work with as much or as little parameters (for python)

Comment: If that's so, I'm not sure you can do it. If `where` clause is as you posted it and you don't pass any of those parameters, it just won't work. I don't see how would changing a *function* help in this case.

Comment: I will definitely pass the variables but my function has to account for other sql queries as well and different queries may have different parameters in "where" clause, which I will always pass, but I need to do that with same function readdata so my readdata must work as readdata(filename) and also as readdata(filename,param1,param2)

Comment: Aha. Try to set parameters' default values, e.g. `function readdata(filename, param1 in varchar2 default null, param2 in varchar2 default null)`

Comment: i may have a sql query with 100 params and this may not be the best idea though